# ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, oracle-apex

Why this procedure can't run? It compiles correctly but when i try to insert something it shows me this error: **ORA-04098: trigger 'SAMPLEDATA.BI_STUDENTS' is invalid and failed re-validation**.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_new_student (
  pName   NVARCHAR2, 
  pPhone NVARCHAR2,
  pReg DATE,      
  pBirth DATE
)
AS
  -- declare variables.
  v_student_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- add a record.
  INSERT INTO STUDENTS (STUDENT_ID, NAME, PHONENUMBER, REGISTRATIONDATE, BIRTHDAY)
  VALUES (student_id_seq.nextval, pName, pPhone, pReg, pBirth)
  RETURNING STUDENT_ID INTO v_student_id;
END insert_new_student;
```

//

```
BEGIN
  insert_new_student( 'A', '012345', SYSDATE, '01/26/2017');
END
```

//

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BI_STUDENTS" 
  before insert on "STUDENTS"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."STUDENT_ID" is null then 
    select "STUDENTS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."STUDENT_ID" from sys.dual; 
  end if; 
end;
```

Comment: 1. Check whether you have a trigger on that table for Insert operations: 2. Try to Insert directly, without procedure.

Comment: Check your triggers: `select so.name, text
from sysobjects so, syscomments sc
where type = 'TR'
and so.id = sc.id
and text like '%YoutTableName%' ; `

Comment: I have a trigger on that table...

Comment: If you disable the trigger and then try again, it'll probably work. You might want to edit your question and add the trigger source code, too.

Comment: I didn't create trigger but when i write select * from all_triggers
where table_name = 'STUDENTS' it showed me that there is trigger on that table.

Comment: Object status is invalid of this trigger

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:
SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER SAMPLEDATA.BI_STUDENTS;

What is the output?

Run the following:
select * 
from user_errors 
where type = 'TRIGGER' 
and name = 'BI_STUDENTS';

What is the result?

Comment: BI.Students - 1. identifier 'NEW.STUDENTS_ID' must be declared and 2. PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: From your previous example, it looks like the column name should be STUDENT_ID, not STUDENTS_ID as it is in the trigger.

Comment: Yes, but it is the same error when i change it to NEW.STUDENT_ID

Comment: If you have defined sequence and do not want to use trigger to insert that THEN just disable trigger OR Insert data without ID and trigger will do that instead...